# Can someone explain the significance of Certificate Signature algorithm in the selection of Cipher suite in a TLS communication?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

Can someone explain the significance of Certificate Signature algorithm  in the selection of Cipher suite in a TLS communication?

Comment: @schroeder I am trying to understand if the signature algorithm of a certificate has any role in the ciphersuite selection during the TLS communication.

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer, thank you.

Comment: In the past , CloudFlare did this: https://blog.cloudflare.com/sha-1-deprecation-no-browser-left-behind/.  Returning SHA-1 or SHA-2 signed certificate depending on how the client presented itself (in order to help old clients blocked at the SHA-1 case). So it is kind of the exact reverse: based on what crypto algorithms the client presented, the server offered a certificate signed differently.